# Laravel store function changes return data

Tags: php, json, laravel

Quite sure I'm doing something wrong here, just don't know what or where.

I have a Laravel controller that handles an ajax post request and returns the results of a curl request to that ajax call:

```
public function store()
{
        /** Receive long and lat through ajax **/
        $long = Input::get('longitude');
        $lat = Input::get('latitude');
        $location = $lat . "," . $long;
        $url = blablable;
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, 
            array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => $url
                ));
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        return $result;
        curl_close($curl);
}
```

This works: the curl returns a JSON array, which gets passed back to the ajax call.

But now I want to save the incoming data to the database:

```
$location = new Location();
$location->latitude = Input::get('latitude');
$location->longitude = Input::get('longitude');
$location->save();
```

I add those 4 lines at the top of the function, the data gets saved to the database but the JSON array get's grabbled, somehow `<!-- app/models/Location.php -->` gets added to the top of the return, making the JSON array invalid.

No clue as to what is causing this so any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated!

-- Edit 1 --

The result of `Input::all();` is

```
array(2) {
 ["latitude"]=>
 string(10) "50.8809794"
 ["longitude"]=>
 string(9) "4.6920714"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `dd(Input::all())` put at beginning of the store method?

Comment: Another thing, the `curl_close($curl);` should be before the return statement.

Comment: Edited the question with the results of Input::all(). Closed the curl before the return.

Comment: What about the `dd($result)` before the return?

Comment: $location becomes an `Eloquent` object after the save. You schould call $location->toJson()? perhaps i do not understand you: are you saying Input::all(); get malformed after you save the location?

Comment: Do you have any Location model event handlers? I suspect you are printing something in the Location::saving() event

Comment: @carlosdubusm was right, there were 2 lines commented out at top of my model file and those were being printed somehow. Removing them fixed it.

Comment: Changes your variable when saving to the database, and you can using 'teepluss/api' for doing curl, it would be nice.. i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as a solution, but as a way to clean up your code a bit:

1. You don't need to use `curl` and can use `Request::create()` and `Route::dispatch()` instead.
2. You should use the `protected $fillable` attribute in your model, to clean up the new entry.

Your code can become:

```
public function store()
{
    // This is for saving the entry
    $location = new Location();
    $location->fill(Input::all());
    $location->save();

    // This is for the cURL 
    // (assuming this is a GET requst, but other methods are available)
    $request = Request::create('/path/to/url/', 'GET');

    $response = Route::dispatch($request);

    // Do stuff with the $response or just return it
    return $response;
}
```